# What is this binary in tflearn installation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

I am trying to install tflearn on my system. They want me to install binary,

```
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

so what is binary?I am not able find any proper documentation in regards to this.

Comment: A `.whl` or "wheel" is just a python [built-package format](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel) for distributing Python libraries. If there are, for example, C-extensions then the wheel will come with pre-compiled binaries for your system (note your .`whl` filename indicates it is for Cpython 2.7 on linux wiht x86_64 architecture).

Answer (score 0):

you should just run:

```
pip install -U tensorflow==1.0 
pip install tflearn
```